# Name for a new music group - translation of “Heal the World”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I’m founding an early music group dedicated to donating to climate change action, and I’d love to name the group, “Heal the World”, but in Latin, rather than English. I’d be very grateful for translation help, as my junior high Latin courses were many moons ago. I want the order to be addressed to many, not a person at a time.

Rather than Sanate Mundum, what about  Recurare Mundum? Medeor Mundum? Salvificem Mundum? The latter meaning, “save the world”, I presume?

Are these conjugated correctly and is the vocabulary appropriate? I’m hesitant to use “sanate” just because it’s a cognate to “sanitize” in English, which sounds a bit unpleasant for the name of an ensemble. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! The name "Heal the World" appears to be an order. Is it given to one person ("you individual, heal the world") or several ("all of you together, heal the world")? It makes a difference in Latin. Please edit your question to add details.

Comment: Thanks! Several people -- all of you together, heal the world.

Comment: I edited that into your question and wrote up an answer. Please [take a look at our introductory tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) to see the basic functions of the site. And of course, feel free to edit your question further if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the word *mundus* for "world" and *sanare* for "heal".
There are also other options like *orbis* and *curare*.
You can check and compare the words — and find new ones — in any of [the many online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
(The verbs are often listed as *sano* and *curo* instead of *sanare* and *curare*.)

With these words, the order would be ***Mundum sanate***, "heal the world".
Either word order is fine, so *Sanate mundum* works as well if it sounds better to you.

Comment: thanks! What about Solvitur Mundum?
Medeor Mundum?
Salvificem Mundum? (Save the world, I presume). Are these conjugated correctly and is the vocabulary appropriate? I’m hesitant to use “sanate” just because it’s a cognate to “sanitize” in English, which sounds a bit unpleasant for the name of an early music ensemble. Thanks!